# Is it safe to keep luggage in a car in London and nearby areas?

Tags: london, automobiles, security, england

My wife and I will be travelling to London in a few months. While we're there, we're going to get a rental car to go see a few things outside of the city. We'll be staying in a different hotel during that time, so we will have our luggage with us when we go to a couple places.

Based on the rental car options, I don't know if we'll be able to get a car with a separate trunk. Is it safe to leave luggage visible in a car? If not, what would be the best way to keep our luggage safe?

In case it matters, the specific locations are Leavesden studios, Chawton cottage, and Hampton Court.

Comment: Without even knowing the first thing about those neighborhoods, the answer is **NO.** The answer is No anywhere in the world.

Comment: I think the second question: `what would be the best way to keep our luggage safe?` is more answerable since it's not as opinion-based.

Comment: @JoErNanO Respectfully, any question that starts out "what is the best..." is too broad. There is my opinion of what is best, and there is yours and the twain shall (possibly) never meet.

Comment: @CGCampbell Yes indeed. One can however substitute the `best` with a more quantitative judgement and there you have a nice [tag:tips-and-tricks] question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The places you have mentioned are in three of the '[home counties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_counties)': Herts, Hants, and Surrey, and I have tooled around two of the venues (never been to the Harry Potter film sets).  It's debatable whether it makes sense to rent a car to visit popular tourist venues in the home counties, but that's a topic relying heavily upon your experience in South East England combined with your agenda. The home counties are thought to be safer than say Brixton or Wood Green, but it is not prudent to assume this.

Some of the hotels in those locations have a car park located either under the hotel or in a flood lit area, but even in the best of conditions you wouldn't want to leave your stuff in a car overnight.  Put simply, it's [poor form](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Poor%20Form).

The rule goes for stuff that's visible or stored in the boot.  Nobody will sympathise if anything goes missing or if the car windows are damaged; you can expect the police to sigh and roll their eyes.  If you want to keep your stuff safe overnight, carry it into the hotel.

In the day time at those venues, it's generally ok to leave your stuff visible if you are in the venue's car park (but not the overflow car park), but even then people like to cover it with a [car blanket throw](https://www.google.com/search?q=car%20blanket%20throw&tbm=isch) stowed in the boot for that purpose.  Look around at what other people are doing, the global rule "[monkey see, monkey do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation)" applies.